# Classification Ensemble with Random Forest as base classifier

Tags: random-forest, ensemble-learning

I have created a classification ensemble with random forest as a base classifier. Each random forest has 500 trees. There are total 100 such forests in the ensemble. Majority voting is being used as the voting scheme. I was expecting the classifier to perform marginally better than a single random forest. However, its performance is drastically poorer than the random forest. Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: Very simply put: If you have a loot of bad forests, with majority vote, they will take over the vote and can certainly perform poorer than one good tree. How do you build those forests?

Comment: Each forest is a random forest based on bagging technique. The number of features splitting at each node i.e. mtry is set to square root of total number of features.

Then each of such random forest is trained with whole training set and each trained forest is tested on same training set. Then majority voting is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all: Training set should not be Test-set. Use cross-validation or something similiar.

Then try different voting techniques, you will see differrent results. But the way you are doing this there is much of a reason why the average opinion of 500 forests should be better than the opinion of one forest.

Comment: Yes, training set and test set are different.  But, is there a reason why the ensemble is not performing better or at least as good as random forest?

Comment: Well, if you use majority voting you expect any number of random forests to perform the exact same as a single random forest. If you instead of majority voting for example gave them votes depending on their accuracy, you would expect better results.

Comment: That is what I believed that the ensemble would perform like a single random forest. However, it is performing much worse than a single random forest.